# Vmware ESXi 4.1 won't boot correctly

Tags: vmware-esxi

I had a frozen VM on an ESXi 4.1 machine.

I attempted to kill it using the usual methods, but nothing seemed to work, so I rebooted the host machine fully.

Now when the host machine (not the VM!) boots, all I see is ...

> SYSLINUX 3.63 0x4afa90e9 EBIOS
>   Copyright (c) 1994-2008 H. Peter Anvin

for maybe 30 seconds or so, and then a blinking cursor comes up, and nothing seems to happen from there.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start? The server hardware seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the system did eventually boot, after about 3 hours.

One of the hard drives in the raid array had corrupted, once it was swapped out everything was fine again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ESXi 4.1 CD, you can try re-installing the VMware ESXi Hypervisor.

Then once you are done with it, you may have to re-do the settings for the VMware Host.

Note that if repair is not available, you will need to re-install the host. In that case anything on the datastore where you will install the VMware Hypervisor will be deleted.